# Jenkins + Selenium WebDriver + MSTest issue

Tags: selenium, jenkins, mstest

I have created a test method in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate that checks for the existance of two text boxes. I instantiate "InternetExplorerDriver" in the AssemblyInitialize() method and have setup Jenkins (on Windows 7) to run the MSTest method using the MSTestRunner plugin. The test seem to pass but I'm not seeing the DOS command window that I see when the "InternetExplorerDriver" instantiates and also I'm not seeing the Internet Explorer browser from loading the web page at all even though the test has passed. I also call the Quit() method on the webdriver in AssemblyCleanup. I'm running Jenkins service as my own NT account on my local box as running the service as "Local System Account" has issues. Here's my code snippet:

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDriverDirectory, ieOptions);
```

The ieDriverDirectory has the InternetExplorerServer.exe running in 32bit mode. When I run the same test method from Visual Studio 2010 IDE or from the mstest.exe /testcontainer:, I'm able to see the DOS command window loading with the port number, the browser loading, the test method passing and the browser closing at the end when Quit() is called.

Comment: The Local System account doesn't have a desktop, as far as I know, thus you won't see it. This may be wrong, I'd have to dig up a few blog posts. Why does this matter? If you are worried the test isn't doing anything, put some logging in place.

Comment: I did more logging and it looks like the test cases are passing for real as I'm seeing this in the Console output in Jenkins: "Started ChromeDriver (v2.0) on port 42600". On purpose, I changed the URL to a wrong one and the test case failed as expected. The only thing I'm surprised is why I'm not able to see the DOS window open up during the IE and Chrome driver instantiation and why I'm not seeing the browser getting loaded while I see all when I run from within Visual Studio 2010 IDE and also from the command line thru mstest.exe

Comment: It happened with me on a TFS build server. It turns out there is a checkbox "Run Build agent as an interactive service". When I check this, I can see the dos window and i can see tests running on browser. You can find a similar setting in jenkins.